# silverlight: how to display different views in listbox based on items object type?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, mvvm, windows-phone-7

Say, I've got two classes: `AppleViewModel` and `OrangeViewModel`. And I've got an `ObservableCollection<object>` of `AppleViewModel`'s and `OrangeViewModel`'s.

There are also two corresponding views: `AppleView` and `OrangeView`.

In app.xaml, there are DataTemplates for them:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AppleTemplate">
        <local:AppleView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="OrangeTemplate">
        <local:OrangeView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

And a converter just in case:

```
public class MyContentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value is AppleViewModel)
            return Application.Current.Resources["AppleTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
        else if (value is OrangeViewModel)
            return Application.Current.Resources["OrangeTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
        else return null;
    }
}
```

It is referenced:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <local:MyContentConverter x:Key="cConverter"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

And this is the `<ListBox/>`:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{Binding Converter={StaticResource cConverter}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

It shows just blank screen. How can I fix it so that the listbox would show different views for apples and oranges?

Comment: Realize this is an older post, but silverlight 5 now has Implicit Data Templates http://jesseliberty.com/2011/04/21/implicit-data-templates-silverlight-5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DataContext for a ContentControl's ContentTemplate is actually the Content of the ContentControl and not its DataContext. So the problem may be that your Views is getting Null as DataContext.

Try it like this

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"
                            ContentTemplate="{Binding Converter={StaticResource cConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Update**
Try to add some static info to your AppleView and OrangeView and see if it works

**OrangeView**

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Orange" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Orange View:"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**AppleView**

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Green" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Apple View:"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Also, I uploaded my sample app here so you can compare it to yours:
http://www.mediafire.com/?dqy47c69zgcmcnv

Comment: @Mikhail Orlov: So you don't just get a blank screen anymore? In that case I think the DataContext is the problem. I updated my answer a little and also uploaded my sample app so you can compare it to yours

Comment: For some reason, adding `Content="{Binding}"` works after restarting computer. There should be some bug in the emulator or tools. Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: Can you please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578128/list-box-with-multiple-data-template-style-for-selected-item